# Is the hyperbolic plane convex?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic, noneuclidean-geometry

I'm attending a lecture series about introduction to non-Euclidian Geometry, but it is focused on the intuition of that topic without giving me the tools to analize the following question:

Is the hyperbolic plane convex?

Where convex here means that there is geodesic line between any two points in the set.

At one side I feel like it should be convex, because $\mathbb{H}$ has no 'obstructions', but the 'abundante of space' makes me wonder if could be a straight line connecting any two points. I would be glad to see a proof of it.

Comment: What do you know about hyperbolic space and it's geodesic?

Comment: Yes, it is convex. Moreover it is uniquely geodesic as any CAT(0) space. You can read the book by Bridson and Haefliger (the first few pages) about it.

Comment: By definition, any stand-alone space must be convex because there is no way to consider a point outside of the space. If a saddle is embedded in Euclidean space then we can construct line segments outside of the saddle but that is not the case with hyperbolic space because geodesics can only consist of points in the space.

Comment: @JohnDouma: In this question "convexity" is a purely intrinsic property of a Riemannian manifold. A saddle embedded in Euclidean space has its own Riemannian metric, obtained by restriction of the Euclidean metric on each tangent plane, and depending on the detailed meaning of "saddle" it is probably also convex in this intrinsic sense. And a "stand-alone" space need not be convex in this intrinsic sense.

Comment: @LeeMosher According to the definition of convexity for Reimann manifolds in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76875/convex-hull-on-a-riemannian-manifold we are talking about the same thing. I.e. a set is convex if all geodesics between two points are contained in the set. By that definition, wouldn't the entire manifold be convex?

Comment: That link does not define convexity of a Riemannian manifold. Instead, given a complete Riemannian manifold $M$, it defines convexity of a subset $C$ of $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tool you can use to answer this question: In the upper half plane model of the hyperbolic plane
$$\mathbb H^2 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid y > 0\}
$$
(with the metric $ds^2 = \frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}$), the geodesic lines are the Euclidean semicircles that hit the $x$-axis at right angles and the Euclidean vertical rays that are based at points on the $x$-axis.

Now convince yourself that for any two points $p,q \in \mathbb H^2$ there exists a geodesic line containing both $p$ and $q$, i.e. either a Euclidean semicircle through $p$ and $q$ hitting the $x$-axis at right angles or a Euclidean vertical ray through $p$ and $q$ based at a point on the $x$-axis.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.